# Show that $\ker T$ is a maximal linear subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a non-zero linear form defined on linear space V. Show that $\ker T$ is a maximal linear subspace of $V$, which means that if $\ker T \subset W$ for some subspace $W \subset V$ then $W = \ker T$ or $W = V$.

Would be great to get a little hint :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear form means linear functional I hope which I mean map from vector space to its scalar field.

$T:V\to F$ so $\dim ker(T)+\dim Im(T)=n\Rightarrow \dim(KerT)=n-1$

$V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $F$, $F$ over $F$ is of dimension $1$ as a vector space.

I hope you can take it from here!

Comment: Ofc! I forgot that $Im (T)$ is one dimensional. Thank you very much :)