# Yes/No : Is the quotient $\ker(g) / \ker(f)$ is zero-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

> let $V$  be  a real  finite  dimensional  vector space  and  $f,g$ are nonzero linear functional on $V$ real vector space,Assume that  $Ker(f)\subset Ker(g)$ Is   statements is true/false ?
>
> Is  $\frac{ker(g)}{ker(f)}\cong\mathbb{R}$?

## My attempt : I think  yes

by rank Nullity theorem it is correct  because $\dim kerf = \dim ker g$ so $\dim(\frac{ker(g)}{ker(f)})\cong dim(\mathbb{R})=1$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel of a non-zero linear form on an $n$-dimensional vector space is of dimension $n-1$ by the rank theorem. Hence both your kernels have the same dimension. As one kernel is included in the other they are equal. So the quotient zero.

Comment: what is the  meaning of quotient zero ??

Comment: It means that they are equal. I was speaking about quotient because you formulate your question in terms of a quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [null spaces of linear functionals  are maximal subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827627/show-that-ker-t-is-a-maximal-linear-subspace-of-v). So $\ker f$ and $\ker g$ are maximal subspaces and $\ker f \subset \ker g $ implies $\ker f=\ker g$. So....?

Comment: nice  sirji    is  ur  baby  ?? in photo

Comment: The proof is just using the rank theorem. While bothering for a reference for this ?

Comment: No! its my brother's son!

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj: Actually Hoffman prove the converse too, namely, every maximal subspace is null space of some linear functional. Thats why I mention this

Comment: With all dued respect, we don't care about the converse. (For proving the quotient is zero.) The only sound argument is "they both have same finite dimension by rank theorem, as one is included in the other, they are equal."

Comment: I agree and I just  mention the link. Now is it okay?

Comment: Here again, after your edit, I simply not understand why you don't want to use the rank theorem. :) I mean, it *must* be mentioned. But I agree, it is not imprtant debating this.